# Rails Best Gem Or Plugin For Connecting To Multiple Databases using Same Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am Using Rails 3.0.3 Application. In My Application I need to interact with multiple databases dynamically at run time.

Requirement:

1] In future I may be need to add some more databases. It should support that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

To interact with multiple databases you can use Connection Ninja. Please [follow this link](https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja). There you can see that works even with rails 3, just install it using:

```
gem install connection_ninja
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for reply. But once i generated model. I have mentioned in migration file like

require 'connection_ninja' use_connection_ninja(database_name).

Now i run rake db:migrate then it is throwing error like

undefined method `use_connection_ninja' for main:Object.

what i need to do now?

Comment: Please note that you must use it not in migrations but in Models:      class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  use_connection_ninja(:other_database)
end There is a good abstraction to use it along many models in the link I  mentioned to you. Hope that helps